# How to enable use of SSL in MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, python, ssl, mariadb-10.3

I have 2 devices on my local network: a remote MySQL server (using MariaDB 10.3) and a laptop (acting as a client with Python). I need to connect to a remote MySQL server via Python using SSL encryption.

When I try to connect to a remote MySQL server without using SSL everything works good:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
HOST = "192.168.1.8"
DATABASE = "some_database_name"
USER = "ssluser"
PASSWORD = "some_password"
db_connection = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)
print("Connected to:", db_connection.get_server_info())
```

Got the message:

```
Connected to: 5.5.5-10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
```

But when I try to connect using SSL, I get the error:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
HOST = "192.168.1.8"
DATABASE = "some_database_name"
USER = "ssluser"
PASSWORD = "some_password"

SSL_ca='/etc/mysql/ssl/ca.pem'
SSL_cert='/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem'
SSL_key='/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem'

db_connection = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, ssl_ca=SSL_ca, ssl_cert=SSL_cert, ssl_key=SSL_key, port=3306, ssl_verify_cert=True)
print("Connected to:", db_connection.get_server_info())
```

Got the error:

```
InterfaceError: 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it
```

> `SSL is required but the server doesn't support it`

On a remote MySQL server, I entered the following commands and received the following messages:

1. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';`

> ```
> +---------------------+--------------------------------+
> | Variable_name       | Value                          |
> +---------------------+--------------------------------+
> | have_openssl        | NO                             |
> | have_ssl            | DISABLED                       |
> | ssl_ca              | /etc/mysql/ssl/cacert.pem      |
> | ssl_capath          |                                |
> | ssl_cert            | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem |
> | ssl_cipher          | TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3                |
> | ssl_crl             |                                |
> | ssl_crlpath         |                                |
> | ssl_key             | /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem  |
> | version_ssl_library | YaSSL 2.4.4                    |
> +---------------------+--------------------------------+
> ```

2. `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';`

> ```
> +---------------+-------+
> | Variable_name | Value |
> +---------------+-------+
> | Ssl_cipher    |       |
> +---------------+-------+
> ```

3. `STATUS`

> ```
> --------------
> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv8l) using readline 5.2
>
> Connection id:        15
> Current database: 
> Current user:     root@localhost
> SSL:          Not in use
> Current pager:        stdout
> Using outfile:        ''
> Using delimiter:  ;
> Server:           MariaDB
> Server version:       10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Raspbian 10
> Protocol version: 10
> Connection:       127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
> Server characterset:  utf8mb4
> Db     characterset:  utf8mb4
> Client characterset:  utf8mb4
> Conn.  characterset:  utf8mb4
> TCP port:     3306
> Uptime:           13 hours 21 min 3 sec
>
> Threads: 8  Questions: 17  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 17  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 11  Queries per second avg: 0.000
> --------------
> ```

In the config file `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` on the remote server I have set the following settings, below the line `[mysqld]`:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/ssl/cacert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem

ssl-cipher = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3

ssl = on
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've commented out below in cnf

#skip_ssl